# Are “la malplej juna” and “la plej maljuna” entirely interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice

Are *la malplej juna* and *la plej maljuna* entirely interchangeable? If so, which one is the most common?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. They are interchangeable according David K. Jordan, in his book titled Being Colloquial in Esperanto. (I don't have the page  number for this reference).

In the Tekstaro, **plej mal-** occurs 800 times. Whereas **malplej** occurs 67 times.

In Google, a search for **"la plej maljuna"** (with quotes) results in 50,400 hits. Whereas, "la malplej juna" (with quotes) results in 73 hits.

Based on this info, it is more common to use **la plej maljuna** instead of the other syntax.

Comment: Thank you, that seems very reasonable! I just learned about Tekstaro, so next time I'll give it a try myself. I'll see if I can get my hands on that book as well.

Comment: It is an excellent book, and has lots of great info, but it is a little boring.

Comment: I believe the reference you're thinking of is **4.5. Comparisons of Adjectives & Adverbs** in which Jordan lists an example with *sincera* and says that it is "usually immaterial" whether mal- is attached to the original adjective or adverb or to the plej.

Answer (score 23):

No, they are not **entirely** interchangeable any more than a pair like the following are entirely interchangeable.

- He is the most pleasant one of the bunch.
- He is the least annoying one of the bunch.

This particular pair (*malplej juna / plej maljuna*) may lead you to point to the same person, but they are not **completely** interchangeable since they draw your attention to different aspects and so may have different connotations.

Consider:

- *La plej juna* - the youngest one.
- *La malplej maljuna* - the least elderly one.

These have different connotations.

Comment: Nice explanation.Bona klarigo de @tomaso-alexander.