# "Pli malgranda" aŭ "malpli granda"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Mi volas diri "smaller". Ĉu estas ajna alieco en signifo inter "pli malgranda" kaj "malpli granda"? Ĉu ili estas ĝuste samaj?

---

I want to say "smaller". Is there any difference in meaning between "pli malgranda" and "malpli granda"? Are they exactly the same?

Comment: Sama demando:
https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/are-la-malplej-juna-and-la-plej-maljuna-entirely-interchangeable

Comment: Mi ne konsentas. Mi pensas ke la uzo de malpli/pli estas malsama ol ”la plej...”/”la malplej ...”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Pli malgranda" estas la supereca komparativo de "malgranda". "Malpli granda" estas la malsupereca komparativo de "granda". Vidu [vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/#komparativo)

La diferenco estas la sama en la angla. "Smaller" - "not as big / less big".

"Pli malgranda" is the positive comparative of "malgranda". "Malpli granda" is the negative comparative of "granda". See [vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/#komparativo)

The difference is the same in English. "Smaller" - "not as big / less big".

Comment: Would one use them differently?

Comment: Just as you would in English. If you want to compare the smallness use pli malgranda, if you want to compare the bigness, use malpli granda. It's a question of your own subjective communicative intention.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that you are buying a sofa. Your friend points to one next to you. You think that the sofa is huge. You want a smaller, more regular sized one. In this case, you would use *malpli granda.*

Now, imagine that you are buying a paintbrush. Your friend points to one next to you. You think that the paintbrush is small, but you need a really tiny one. In this case you would use *pli malgranda.*

Another example: there are two dogs playing in the park and someone asks you which dog is yours. *”Mia hundo estas la...”*

- Both dogs are big - *la malpli granda*
- Both dogs are small - *la pli malgranda*
- One is big, one is small - *la malgranda*